# DataComboBox SelectedValue property 

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a "Form" on which their is DataComboBox and it is data bound.
When user clicks the DataComboBox a DataGridView comes as POPUP which contains Bound data.

```
DataComboBox1.TblData = getTable;// get data contains datasource
DataComboBox1.ValueColumn = "GroupName";
DataComboBox1.ColumnNameList = "AccountGroupID|GroupName|ParentGroup|AlternateGroupName|Annex";
```

Now on Form Load I want to set its SelectedVlaue property of DataComboBox to some numeric value.

For that i am writing the following code .

```
DataComboBox1.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(DtData.Rows[0]["AccountGroupID"]);   
// DtData.Rows[0]["AccountGroupID"] contains value "2";
```

But the above code is not working ,because the SelectedValue property is showing null value.

Comment: What is a `DataComboBox`?  Can you post a link to it on msdn?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
DataComboBox1.SelectedText = Convert.ToInt32(DtData.Rows[0]["AccountGroupID"]).toString();
```

Comment: @ Ibrahim, Actually i want to set "AccountGroupName" as display "AccountGroupId"  as value.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not sure what a `DataComboBox` is, can you try this:

```
DataComboBox1.SelectedValue = (DataComboBox1.TblData != null) &&
   (DataComboBox1.TblData.Count > 0) ? DataComboBox1.TblData[0] : null;
```